# running an "if else" statement in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

suppose I have a dataframe `df`.
I want to create a new column, `HighRenew` and define its value as : " **if the country's `% Renewable` value is at or above the median for all countries in the top 15 the value must be 1, else it must be a 0**"
this is the code i wrote :

```py
df = answer_one()['% Renewable'].to_frame()
med = np.median(df)
df['HighRenew'] = 1 if df['% Renewable'] >= med else 0
```

when i run this, it raises the following error :

- **ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().**

---

- i have the read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o) as well but have not find any solutions.
- i know i can just use `.apply()` and get the same result. but i was wondering if there's any equivalent in an idiomatic pandas way

i haven't find anything specific to this problem on SO or official documents as well

Comment: something like this? `df['% Renewable'].ge(med)`

Comment: `df['HighRenew'] = (df['% Renewable'] >= med).astype(int)` ? You can cast boolean to integer quite easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to return chosen elements from a condition is using `np.where()`.

```
df['HighRenew'] = np.where(df['% Renewable'] >= med, 1, 0)
```

Or the same could be achieved with a list comprehension, but comprehensions can be slower. `df['HighRenew'] = [1 if i >= med else 0 for df['% Renewable']]`